# Enable Page Indexing on GridView with List as its Data Source

Tags: list, c#-4.0, gridview

I want to enable page Indexing on a Grid View which I created from a List.

The List Looks like below

```
public class SearchResults
    {
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string mname { get; set; }
        public string lname { get; set; }

    }
```

I add data to this list and GridViewfrom the following method:

```
SearchResults result= new SearchResults();// Class Variable      
Void Search()
{

result.fname="John";
result.mmane="Cody";
result.lmane="lname";
SearchResults.Add(result);
Gridview1.DataSource=result;
Gridview1.DataBnd();
}
```

Since, I wanted to enable paging Indexing for this page I created an event for it which looks like the below code

```
protected void On_PageIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {

        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        Gridview1.DataSource=result;
        Gridview1.DataBnd();


    }
```

Even after binding the gridview in the page Index event its not working,

Any idea of what might be happening? Can someone explain me how  to bind the list results to the grid view page indexing?

Thanks.

Comment: All variables are disposed at the end of the page's lifefycle. You have to reload the datasource after paging(or sorting etc). Another option is to store it in a `Session` variable. However, i would use this approach only when the web-app is an intranet application with few users.

Comment: When I change Indexing will I need to reload the page? Can you give an example for my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
public class SearchResults
{
   public string fname { get; set; }
   public string mname { get; set; }
   public string lname { get; set; }
}
```

set your markup like this in .aspx page:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Gridview1" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="PageIndexChanging" PageSize="4">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Write following code in your code behind (.aspx.cs) :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!IsPostBack)
      {
         // Get list of search and bind data with Grid
         this.Search();
      }
    }

    private void  Search()
    {
        var searchResults = new List<SearchResults>();
        var search = new SearchResults { fname = "John" };
        searchResults.Add(search);
        search = new SearchResults { fname = "John2" };
        searchResults.Add(search);

        search = new SearchResults {fname = "Micheal" };
        searchResults.Add(search);

        search = new SearchResults { fname = "Sara" };
        searchResults.Add(search);

        search = new SearchResults { fname = "Jenne" };
        searchResults.Add(search);

        search = new SearchResults { fname = "Mac" };
        searchResults.Add(search);

        this.Gridview1.DataSource = searchResults;
        this.Gridview1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Gridview1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        this.Search();
    }
```